# asp.net jquery loading values on page after post back

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

Im currently trying to use a jQuery plugin:
[jQuery Autocomplete Tokenizer](http://loopj.com/2009/04/25/jquery-plugin-tokenizing-autocomplete-text-entry/)
Now after posting back the page, I want to re-load the values back into the textbox for whatever items had been entered.

Now the jQuery on the page is like below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=txtPeople.ClientID %>").tokenInput("Handler.ashx", {
            hintText: "Type in a name",
            noResultsText: "No results",
            searchingText: "Searching...",
            prePopulateFromInput: true  
            },
            prePopulate:  **Here is where I want to add JSON listing the items that should be populated**
        });
    });
```

If I add the JSON below within the prepopulate it loads the values the first time the form loads (And after any postbacks, so I need a way to make this a variable, that I can feed into the javascript on the page, and also have it updated by any client side changes)

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Ben"},{"id":2,"name":"Bernard"},{"id":3,"name":"Joe Bentley"}]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction or give any references that may help? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to assign the json to a variable as in..

```
string prepopulateValues="[{/"id/":1, /"name/":/"Ben/"}"; //etc.
```

then in your jquery function write out the value of the variable

```
prePopulate: <%= prepopulateValues%>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, this appears to work after a postback, although I have the issue of having to set a value on the initial page load, otherwise it errors out and doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you set the value for "prepopulateValues" in the Page_load event?  If you put it in an If(!Postback)? 
Or am i misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: Yeah appears to work, seems very messy but im pretty new to javascript as it is

Answer (score 0):

Or If you are using ASP.Net you can use my opensourse project ASPTokenInput which adds server side functionality to the jquery-tokeninput plugin. This will automatically take care of token persistance across postbacks.

https://github.com/harindaka/ASPTokenInput/wiki